# Push notification: not to replace the old messgaes

Tags: c#, android, json, web-services, push-notification

I have done a push notification to Android, but the content of new message will replace the old one. How to solve that?

The code below:

```
push.QueueNotification(new GcmNotification().ForDeviceRegistrationId("APA91bGZpTp6n3W29RjV_yN3ulNSnP2EAmqccfLQTRdBva_9D7Yy8S-uLqqZ0-gqEn0q2Xwb5o7-v0KEugGjYaX05--8UW17RT4piF5rU0uCjnIwzEc_rwiuo-KY-r1pRe4_ElD65bBExXn2KnbT0iwHTKZmDOqqXw")
.WithJson("{\"notId\":\"1\",\"type\":\"a\",\"caseid\":\"123\",\"contract\":\"a1\",\"title\":\"Message: Type a\",\"message\":\"[a1] \"}")
.WithTag("1"));


push.QueueNotification(new GcmNotification().ForDeviceRegistrationId("APA91bGZpTp6n3W29RjV_yN3ulNSnP2EAmqccfLQTRdBva_9D7Yy8S-uLqqZ0-gqEn0q2Xwb5o7-v0KEugGjYaX05--8UW17RT4piF5rU0uCjnIwzEc_rwiuo-KY-r1pRe4_ElD65bBExXn2KnbT0iwHTKZmDOqqXw")
.WithJson("{\"notId\":\"2\",\"type\":\"b\",\"caseid\":\"456\",\"contract\":\"b1\",\"title\":\"Message: Type b\",\"message\":\"[b1] \"}")
.WithTag("2"));
```

Comment: replace old message where? ion notification bar? db ?

Comment: It could see the 2 different messages on the screen, when i click the message, it will have same content

Comment: use different notification id!

Comment: I have used different notification id 
.WithJson("{\"notId\":\"1\
.WithJson("{\"notId\":\"2\
the result is the same

Answer (score 1):

The key is to set the notification id to all the messages that you want to join together. As can be seen below:

```
mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
int notifyID = 1;
mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("New Message")
    .setContentText("You've received new messages.")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify_status)
numMessages = 0;
// Start of a loop that processes data and then notifies the user
...
mNotifyBuilder.setContentText(currentText)
    .setNumber(++numMessages);
// Because the ID remains unchanged, the existing notification is
// updated.
mNotificationManager.notify(
        notifyID,
        mNotifyBuilder.build());
```

...

Find more here on this link to documentation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating

Comment: I want know my code has any error to occur that result?